# call js function from form action then call php from js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

We can call php directly from form action in html:

```
<form name='x' action = "filename.php">
```

in this case, php will receive all inputs in the form even we don't pass them.

Can we call js function from form action in html?

```
<form name='x' action = "javascript:jsFunction();">
```

Then, call the php from the js function?

```
jsFunction()
{   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;}
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", filename.php, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

**Hint**
I cannot use onsubmit because it log me out from the platform. in other words, it reload the platform from the beginning of the login page.
I am working on integration and I don't have a clear idea about the platform.

**Edit 1:**

Now, in the HTML file:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' id = "myform">

<input type='submit' value='Basic search' onclick = "i2b2.BLAST.jsFunction();">
```

JS file:

```
i2b2.BLAST.jsFunction = function () 
{
   var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
    myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event)
    {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
     };

     xhttp.open("POST", blastresult.php, true);
     xhttp.send();

    event.preventDefault();
}); 
}
```

it reloads the platform from the beginning of the login page!

**Edit2:**

I put some alert to see if the button call the javascript.

```
i2b2.BLAST.jsFunction = function () 
{
   alert('hi');

    this.yuiTabs = new YAHOO.widget.TabView("BLAST-TABS", {activeIndex:1});//this two lines navigate to second tab
    this.yuiTabs.set('activeIndex', 1);

alert('hi');
    myForm.addEventListener('submit', function()
    {
       alert('hi');
        preventDefault();
```

The button call the js and display first 'hi' then navigate to second tab then reload the page. It stop at the second 'hi'.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Sure, you can set an `onsubmit` handler on the form and then call PHP via AJAX.

Comment: @ Johannes Jander  I update my question.

Comment: ` onclick = "i2b2.BLAST.jsFunction(); return false;">`

Comment: @ Johannes Jander it does not return false. just reload the page. could you please see edit 2 in my post? thanks

Comment: your `onclick`-function **should** return false after calling the blast-function. then you can remove `preventDefault()`

Comment: @ Johannes Jander please could you tell me how to write this? did you see my second edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, First give your FORM an id

```
<form id="myForm"></form>
```

then in javascript try this:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e)
{
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
     };

     xhttp.open("POST", filename.php, true);
     xhttp.send();

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: No need to declare "e"?

Comment: you need to declare 'e', to use e.pereventDefault(); method

Comment: event.preventDefault() not working. it reload the page.

Comment: I replace submit in myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) with 'click'

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
<form name='x' action = "javascript:jsFunction();">
```

Use:

```
<form name='x' onsubmit="jsFunction();">
```

You can POST via AJAX as you have shown in your code:

```
function jsFunction(event) {
    // prevent default event from taking place (submitting form to file)
    event.preventDefault();
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;}
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", filename.php, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Though you will need to serialize your data and pass it to `xhttp.send()`, it will need to be form url encoded like: `key1=value1&key2=value2`. You are probably better off using jQuery in the manner @mmm suggests.

Comment: could i use action instead of onsubmit? because it log me out from the platform. in other words, it reload the platform to the login page.

Comment: No, you need to use the onsubmit event in order to prevent the page from reloading (`event.preventDefault()`)

Comment: event.preventDefault() not working. it reload the page.

Comment: sorry, `event.preventDefault()` requires you use an event listener, please take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/91zw6zp9/

Comment: M , I actually using event listener. I am getting crazy.